# iReport doesnt work (org/apache/commons/digester/Digester)

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, zk

I'm using ZK framework 5.0.10 CE and my report is compiled with iReport 4.0.0; I use the next code in java:

```
private void showCuadroComparativo(){
String jdbcSampleReportFile ="/rpt/rptCuadroComparativo3.jrxml";


try {
  Map parameters=new HashMap();
  parameters.put("pIdReq", 3);
  parameters.put("p1", "PERU bitz");
  parameters.put("p2", "T & B");
  parameters.put("p3", "M & H");
  parameters.put("pNombreInstitucion", "ARCHIVO GENERAL DE LA NACION");

  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pbz_logistica?user=root&password=bitz");


  JasperDesign design =JRXmlLoader.load(jdbcSampleReportFile);
  JasperReport report =JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);
  JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters, conn);
  JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print,"sample.pdf");

  conn.close();
} 
catch (JRException ex) {}
catch (SQLException ex) {}    
catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {}
```

}

When I run it, it throws me the following message: org/apache/commons/digester/Digester.

Any suggestion, thanks in advance

Comment: I realize that you're using iReport to design the .jrxml. But as far as I can tell, the question is unrelated to iReport. No?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
 commons-digester-1.7.jar
```

file to your WEB-INF lib folder